# beanstalk beanstalk misconfigured

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a war file into the elastic beanstalk but i keep getting this error:

> health check URL misconfigured

and my environment is set to red.

I gave my applications first html page as the URL for health checkup.

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The health check url must reply with a http status code of 200 (ok), are you sure your root page that you pointe at does that?

Also keep in mind that the elb will load that page fully at every interval you have set, which counts as bandwidth and possibly db/disk IO if it is a really complex page.

If it is, you mght want to jist add a blank hc.html file to your webapp that the health check can load or something simple like that.

or also you can try this command to check url health

```
 curl -i -X HEAD http://qwert.elasticbeanstalk.com
```